# How to read line from notepad.txt?

Tags: command-line, active-directory

I have this query for AD: 
    `for /f %i in (C:\user.txt) do dsquery user -name %i | dsrm -noprompt`

in user.txt I have a name like: 
*"Jose Maria Alvaro"*

When I run the query in command line, it can't pick up the whole name. It picks up only the first name.
Result eg:  `do dsquery user -name Jose`. That is not what I want.

How can I pick the whole name which contains white space?

Comment: Have you tried `-name "%i"` ?  Your program is probably dropping the rest of the argument after the first name.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "DELIMS=" %i in (C:\user.txt) do...
```

The `"delims="` turns off delimiters which default to space and tab, and thus the entire line is delivered as the (default) first token.

See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation.